# how to check a byte array is a valid pdf file or not

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

i have blob data  for PDF files in my database , i want to check that the available blob  file in database is   a valid PDF file or not .can some one help me for this .

Comment: You can try to use one of the libraries working with PDF. Either on opening the file (bytes) or while performing one of operations (e.g. get last string from last page) it will throw if PDF is not PDF.

Answer (score 4):

All pdf files start with the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) 25 50 44 46 (%PDF in ASCII).

Comment: Does 4 correct bytes classify the rest as *valid PDF file*?

Comment: @Sinatr you won't know until you try to read *all* of it.

Comment: I have no idea what a `valid` PDF file is.  The magic number at the start of file indicates it is a PDF file.

Comment: can you help me for how to load a pdf file from byte array  using c# code